# cv2.videocapture doesn't works on Raspberry-pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi2

How can i make the cv2.VideoCapture(0) recognize the USB camera of raspberry-pi.

```
def OnRecord(self, evt):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if (not capture.isOpened()):
        print "Error"
# video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')  # cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter.open("output.mp4", fourcc, 20, (640, 480), True)

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret==True:
            video_writer.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        else:
            break

def OnCancel(self, evt):
    capture.release()
    video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it only prints Error.

So i guess capture is not opening. What might be the reason?

I tried this code from opencv documentation but doesn't worked out for me.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read Answers and comment here [Possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051664/saving-videos-doesnt-work-in-opencv2-python/38054063#38054063)

Comment: Still its a same result.Nothing works at all.

Answer (score 6):

Load the correct video for linux drivers.

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Comment: I have to login to vote and thank you. Very helpful answer!!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with CV2 replacing a webcam source on linux isn't always easy. How OpenCV works is it automatically draws from the systems default video source, which is known (usually) as video0. Unplug your usb webcam and go into a terminal and typing `ls /dev/video*`

Remember the number it says. Now plug in your USB webcam and type in `ls /dev/video*` again and look for any new /video, this is your USB webcam. Now type `mv /dev/videoX videoY` while X is the number of your USB webcam and Y the original number. This will replace your pi's default camera.

This isn't permanent as you will need to do this every time your pi starts up, an alternative to this is creating a bash file that runs on start up. Create a text file and copy the following into it.

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /dev/videoX videoY
```

(replace the X and Y of course)

and place that in `/etc/init.d` directory of your pi. Don't forget you may need to use
`chmod 755 /etc/init.d/FILENAME.sh`
to give it permission to run

Comment: Did this answer help you and if not, what errors did you come across while trying this?

Comment: please take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454655/cv2-videocapture-doesnt-return-frames

Comment: Okay I will take a look at your other question, however did you try switching what your source camera was?

Comment: Its a microsoft USB webcam.

Comment: Well yes you already said it was a USB web camera, however did you try switching the source like in my answer? If so, what happened?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get you then. I tried `ls /dev/video*` after unplugging USB cam but it says No such file or directory. when i plug in my CAM it says `/dev/video0`

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type *lsusb* and check whether the USB camera is recognized or not. If it is recognized then try to give different device ID such as 1 or 2 or 3 rather than 0.

Comment: It recognizes my camera, even i see the webcam live stream.But whenever i try VideoCapture it prints Error and saves only 5.5kb of output file.

Comment: Does it really just print 'Error'? Or is there more information printed? Ist it related to your video camera at all? It seems that writing the image to the video file causes problems, so it may well be independent from the source of the image.  Has the image the same size you specify for frames of the video file?

Comment: Yeah it only prints Error as per my code so i guess capture is not opening.But it creates a file of 5.5kb size in the output folder.So might be a problem in writing the video.

Answer (score 0):

looks Like you might have issue with codec, try using 'MJPG' codec instead of XVID.
For more details have a look [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/)

Comment: `fourcc = cv2.cv.FOURCC(*'MJPG')`                                                                   `video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter.open("output.avi", fourcc, 20, (640, 480), True)`                                                                                                   It also doesn't works.

Comment: If the capture is not opened it should print Error as per my code, so it does prints Error.I also tried .mp4 extension but the result is same.

Comment: Thats odd. Which version of OpenCV you are using?

Comment: I am using opencv 2.3.1

Comment: How about this. fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G')

Comment: I tried `fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G')` when i press Record button it automatically closes my video GUI and prints nothing.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102564/no-video-file-created-by-opencv-2-3-1-with-python-on-raspberry-pi    also first try with separate code just for writing video instead of mixing up things that way its more easier to find out bug.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my complete code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961949/record-webcam-video-with-wxpython-open-cv-using-control-buttons)  correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the camera that you are using is UVC compatible, as openCV running on linux based systems (like a raspi) starts to do some silly things when it is working with non UVC cameras.

Comment: How can i make sure my camera is UVC compatible?