# cv2.VideoCapture doesn't return frames

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython, video-capture, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to save a webcam video with wx Buttons. 
This is my code

```
def OnRecord(self, evt):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if (not capture.isOpened()):
       print "Error"

    # video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')  # cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 9.0, (640, 480), True)

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if not ret:
            print "Capture Failed"
        else:
            out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

But it prints `Capture Failed` until i close the python shell myself. So, i guess `capture.read()` doesn't returns frames. What might be the reason?

How can i make it work? Hope for some expert advice :)

Comment: does it print "Error" in the beginning?

Comment: No i doesn't prints Error it only print `capture failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initialize counter before reading the capture
for Eg:

```
i = 0
while i < 0:
     ret, frame = capture.read()
     if ret:
          out.write(frame)
     else:
          print "Error"
```